# Python returning inappropriate remainder (Modulo)

Tags: python, modulo

I'm new to python and I want you someone to explain me this:

print(9.2%4) must give me the remainder when 4 is divided by 9.2 and the output of the code is 1.1999999999999993 which is clearly not true

But this code: print(9.2/4) gives me output 2.3

Someone please explain this to me

Comment: "_9.2%4 must give me the remainder when 4 is divided by 9.2_" It is the other way around - the remainder is given when 9.2 is divided by 4. I can type `9.2%4` into my Chrome address bar and it does show 1.2 as the answer which is just a rounded off version of the answer you got.

Comment: 9. module 4 is 1.2,. You're getting 1.1999999999999993 because of floating point innacuracy.

Comment: also in python floor division is `//`, so `9.2 // 4 == 2`, `/` is "true division" that will return regular 9.2 divided by 4

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.

> 9.2 % 4 == (8 + 1.2) % 4

You can expand the right side of the above statement as follows:

> ((8 % 4) + (1.2 %4) )

The above can then be simplified as follow:

> (0 + 1.2) == 1.2 == 1.999999999

Comment: wait can you explain me how you got on to third step from second step?

Comment: Okay 8 % 4 is equal to 0 and 1.2 % 4 is equal to 1.9999 which is 1.2.